# @scope("session") - What is the current session?

Tags: spring, session

I am working with Spring Security and Session. I use the annotation @Scope("session") in every proyect class.

I want to know, whats is the current session?, In any class where i am.

Someone knows whats is the code?

Comment: Why do you need `the current session` in any class you have? Instead create just one session scoped bean and autowire it to all places where you need session info.

Comment: Hi. I found here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session that there are 3 ways for working with session in Spring. 
The first is with Session Scoped Beans (my way), follow by the inject the raw Session into a Controller and finally obtaining the raw session. 
I am using @Scope("session") in the related classes with the session, because the objects will be created for each user. If I only use @scope("session") in the first class, other classes will be "singleton" and when I modified some attribute in one session the other user will see it. Do you think that existe other way?

Comment: The solution: if you are using Spring Security, then you could call the current session with the follows code (in somewhere of your code):

User user  = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

In case where you want to create a custom session class, you could write a class that extends of User, but it is other history.

Ref: 9.2 Core Components of https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/